# как изменить value в коде?

Tags: javascript

Есть код

```
<input type="tel" autocomplete="off" class="input-currency__input" data-test="deal-amount-input" maxlength="9" value="1 000">
```

Надо заменить value="1 000" на value="100 000"

```
document.querySelector('.input-currency__input').value = "100 000"
```

меняет визуально

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А так: `document.querySelector('.input-currency__input').setAttribute("value", "100 000");`?